# $a_0 = 15$, $a_1 = 27$, $a_{m+1} = 1$ and for all $k=1,...,m$ $a_k(a_{k+1}-a_{k-1}) = a_k-a_{k-1}-5$. What is $m$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, contest-math

> $a_0 = 15$, $a_1 = 27$, $a_{m+1} = 1$ and $$a_k(a_{k+1}-a_{k-1}) = a_k-a_{k-1}-5$$ for all $k=1,...,m$. What is $m$?

I saw this question in the 2022 Antalya Math Contest but I couldn't figure it out. I've tried letting $k$ equal to m and working my way from there but I immediately got stuck. Any help would be appreciated

Edit:
Thanks to lulu and achille hui's help I've been able to solve it!:

$a_k(a_{k+1}-a_{k-1}) = a_k-a_{k-1}-5 \Leftrightarrow a_k(a_{k+1}-1) - a_{k-1}(a_k - 1) = -5 $

Let $b_n = a_n(a_{n+1}-1)$

We notice that $$b_{n}-b_{n-1} = -5 $$ And therefore $b_k$ is an arithmetic sequence. Considering the initial conditions, we see that $b_n = 390-5n$

Substituting $a_n$ back into the equation we see that $$ a_n(a_{n+1}-1) = 390-5n $$

Plugging in n=m then gives us $ 0 = 390-5m $ and we get 78 as the answer.

Comment: Interesting.  Just playing it out shows that $a_{79}=1$ (and no smaller value works), but I don't instantly see a way to get that without running the recursion....

Comment: Hint: $a_k(a_{k+1} - a_{k-1}) = a_k - a_{k-1} - 5 \iff
 a_k(a_{k+1}-1) - a_{k-1}(a_k - 1) = -5$

Comment: I you should not add the solution to your question but  to post it  as answer and then accept your answer.